# How to disable MD5 signature for Android apk?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, md5, signing

when trying to upload our apk to our Mobile Device Management I get an error saying that "Apps signed with MD5 are not supported anymore".

I am not sure about the signing process. How do I disable MD5 signing?

Greetings

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new project and cloning my code into it. There appears to have been something wrong with Android Studio configurations.